# RxJS: Extracting an array of values from complex json via http

Tags: angular, rxjs, switchmap

Angular 10

(Simplified)

I have an http get that returns a country and a list of States in the country:

```
   {"id":1,
    "countryMeta": 
        {"statesList": 
             [
               {"name":"AB","value":"AB"},
               {"name":"CA","value":"CA"},
             ]}
     }
```

I am trying to get a list of states from this object and put it into a NameValue array, but I only get 1 state out and it's not an array. Shouldn't switchMap do that?

```
    states$ = this.myHttpService.get().pipe(switchMap((x) => x.countryMeta.statesList));
```

Then consumed:

```
*ngFor="let state of states$ | async"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `map`.

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
states$ = this.myHttpService.get().pipe(map((x) => x.countryMeta.statesList));
```

`switchMap` switches to a new observable, `map` transforms current observable.